# initialize default system property in java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, system-properties

Is there a smart way to initialize default system properties in java?

There are some properties which make sense to define each time, e.g. a service port, serverUrl.
But then there are some properties which are required for the application to work correctly which should not change.

> -Djavax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate=org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RuntimeDelegateImpl
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Using `System.setProperty()` might be a solutions, is there a way I can make sure this would be initialized in early startup. In my case I don't have control over the `main()` method since it is an eclipse rcp application.

Comment: You can use a `static` initializer in your main class - that will trigger pretty early. But you might be better off writing a startup script that deals with these flags. Presumably folks aren’t manually running `java -jar` so your wrapper script can deal with this. If you’re using something like Gradle, you can ask it to add defaults into the scripts for you

Comment: For an Eclipse RCP you can add things to the xxx.ini